# Is it true or can it be proven that $\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} \geq \operatorname{rad}(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, divisibility, solution-verification, totient-function

The title says it all:

> Is it true or can it be proven that $\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} \geq \operatorname{rad}(n)$?

Here $n$ is a natural number, $\varphi(n)$ is the [Euler-totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of $n$, and $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) of $n$.

Here is my:

**ATTEMPT AT A PROOF**

We know that
$$\varphi(n) = n\prod_{p \mid n}\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{p}\bigg),$$
so that we obtain
$$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} = \prod_{p \mid n}\bigg(\frac{p}{p-1}\bigg) = \frac{\bigg(\prod_{p \mid n}{p}\bigg)}{\bigg(\prod_{p \mid n}(p-1)\bigg)} = \frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)}{\bigg(\prod_{p \mid n}(p-1)\bigg)}.$$

Since the $p$'s are primes, then $p \geq 2$.  Thus equality holds only when $n$ is a power of two.

Otherwise,
$$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} < \operatorname{rad}(n),$$
since then the
$$\bigg(\prod_{p \mid n}(p-1)\bigg)$$
term in the denominator would be greater than one.

> We therefore conclude that, in general,
>   $$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} \leq \operatorname{rad}(n)$$
>   holds, with equality occurring only if $n$ is a power of two.  (Note that $n=2^0=1$ is included.)

**QUESTION**

> *Does this (dis)proof suffice?*

Comment: Yes, sure, that's fine

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, @HagenvonEitzen.

Comment: No, there must be a typo.  Indeed, you claim the opposite yourself in the last sentence (compare with the title). Counterexample from Wikipedia: $n=504$. Then $\frac{n}{\phi(n)}=\frac{7}{2}\ge  42=\operatorname{rad}(n)$ certainly is not true.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @DietrichBurde!  There is no typo, and there is a reason for the initial "deviation" (mainly for my own self-reference).

Comment: In fact, we have $\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}=\frac{rad(n)}{\varphi(rad(n))}$ and we also have $\varphi(rad(n))\ge 1$  where equality only holds if $rad(n)=1$ , meaning $n=1$ , or $rad(n)=2$ meaning that $n$ is a power of $2$. This immediately gives the correct second inequality. For a disproof of the above equation, one counterexample would be enough, but we can show here in fact more , almost the converse of the original statement.

Comment: Instead of "equation" , I mean "inequality" , but time to correct it was over.

Comment: @Peter, would you care to outline a proof for your claim that
$$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}=\frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)}{\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(n))}?$$
Thank you!  =)

Comment: We have $$\varphi(n)=n\cdot \prod_{p\ prime,p\mid n} (1-\frac{1}{p})$$ , so $\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}$ only depends on the prime factors of $n$, hence the same formula holds for the radical.

Comment: @Peter, what I am not following is:  Why is the following equation true, which is implied by your claim?
$$\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(n)) = \prod_{p \mid n}{\bigg(p-1\bigg)}$$

Comment: Because the Euler-totient function is multiplicative and $\varphi(p)=p-1$ holds for a prime number $p$.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for pointing that out, @mathlove! =)